# Updating null columns with data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to compare with one table and update another table if there are null records. Table `LEGACY_CUST_INFO` has correct `CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER`. So, I need to findout the null records in `CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER` in second table `CUST_INFO` and update `CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER` from first table `LEGACY_CUST_INFO`. Apart from updating `CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER`, I will also need to update `UPDATED` column with `SYSDATE` and `UPDATED_BY` with `'ADMIN'`. `ROW_ID` in both the tables match are an exact match.

Below are the two table structures

Table 1 Name : `LEGACY_CUST_INFO`

```
ROW_ID  CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER UPDATED UPDATED_BY
1-AB 2345 16-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AC 3345 17-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AV 2335 20-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AN 2042 18-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AG 2255 01-JUN-2022 ADMIN
```

Table 2 Name : `CUST_INFO`

```
ROW_ID  CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER UPDATED UPDATED_BY
1-AB NULL 22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AC NULL 22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AV 5409 22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AN NULL 22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AG 8848 22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
```

It is not updating anything when I use the below update. Is there a way to update the nulls ?

```
merge into cust_info dst
using (
select lci.row_id, lci.cust_privilege_number
from legacy_cust_info lci
inner join cust_info ci on ci.row_id = lci.row_id
where ci.cust_privilege_number != lci.cust_privilege_number
) src
on (dst.row_id = src.row_id)
when matched then 
  update set dst.cust_privilege_number = src.cust_privilege_number, dst.updated= sysdate, dst.updated_by = 'ADMIN';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM legacy_cust_info;

ROW_ CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER UPDATED     UPDAT
---- --------------------- ----------- -----
1-AB                  2345 16-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AC                  3345 17-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AV                  2335 20-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AN                  2042 18-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AG                  2255 01-JUN-2022 ADMIN

SQL> SELECT * FROM cust_info;

ROW_ CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER UPDATED     UPDAT
---- --------------------- ----------- -----
1-AB                       22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AC                       22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AV                  5409 22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AN                       22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
1-AG                  5515 22-JUN-2022 ADMIN
```

Use `IS NULL` condition in `MERGE`'s `WHERE` clause because nothing is "equal" to `NULL` so this:  `WHERE d.cust_privilege_number <> s.cust_privilege_number` isn't enough.

```
SQL> MERGE INTO cust_info d
  2       USING legacy_cust_info s
  3          ON (d.row_id = s.row_id)
  4  WHEN MATCHED
  5  THEN
  6     UPDATE SET
  7        d.cust_privilege_number = s.cust_privilege_number,
  8        d.updated = SYSDATE,
  9        d.updated_by = 'ADMIN'
 10             WHERE    d.cust_privilege_number <> s.cust_privilege_number
 11                   OR d.cust_privilege_number IS NULL;

5 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM cust_info;

ROW_ CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER UPDATED     UPDAT
---- --------------------- ----------- -----
1-AB                  2345 21-JUN-2023 ADMIN
1-AC                  3345 21-JUN-2023 ADMIN
1-AV                  2335 21-JUN-2023 ADMIN
1-AN                  2042 21-JUN-2023 ADMIN
1-AG                  2255 21-JUN-2023 ADMIN

SQL>
```

Comment: Sir, this is not working for NULL values. Query results is giving zero rows updated. Requirement is here : "cust_info" table has a column "cust_privilege_number" which have NULL values. So, I need to update the column values from "legacy_cust_info" table.

Comment: Could you post several sample rows for both tables that illustrate the problem and desired result? Do it by editing the original question, not as a comment.

Comment: I added rows in the question for you to visualise

Comment: Do you really have **two** 1-AB ROW_ID values (i.e. duplicates)? Or did you make a typo when creating sample data? If it is not a typo, which LEGACY_CUST_INFO row is to be used?

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. I corrected it. CUST_PRIVILEGE_NUMBER is the row that has right values in LEGACY_CUST_INFO table

Comment: OK; have a look at edited answer, please.